# How to prove that $x^2$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ "topologically"

Tags: general-topology

We define continuity as such in topology: Let $\displaystyle X,Y$ be 
 topological spaces and let $f:X\to Y$ be a function. $f$ is called continuous if and only if for every open $U\subseteq Y$, the set $\displaystyle f^{-1}(U)$ is open.

So how could we prove that $x^2$ is continuous by taking this definition?

sorry im new, so i dont know why it doesnt work :P

Comment: I edited the $\LaTeX$, so it works now.

Comment: thanls yout very much appreciate that.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. So what did you try writing down? What specific open set $U$ did you start with, and what is its preimage? (Start, for example, with $(a,b)$ with $0<a<b$. Then you can consider other cases.) You can edit your post to include your progress on this.

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for formatting tips.

Comment: @TedShifrin i really don't know how to approach the problem, and to show how a set is open. I would really be grateful if you can show it to me once.

Comment: Every open set in $\Bbb R$ is a union of open intervals, so all you need to do is show that the inverse image $f^{-1}(U)$ is a union of open intervals whenever $U$ is an open interval. That's why I suggested my starting place.

Comment: @TedShifrin but how do you show generally whether a set is open or not ? is there an approach ?

Comment: Surely the course you are taking has shown you this. What is the definition of an open set?

Comment: @TedShifrin im trying to learn it on my own :) for every x of U we can find an epsilon such that the epsilon-ball of x is still in U

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tends to be that when you want to show that a particular function is continuous, your proof will be essentially the same as a $\delta$-$\varepsilon$ proof. In particular, a set $U$ being *open* means that for every $x\in U$ there is some positive $c$ such that the interval $(x-c,x+c)$ is a subset of $U$.

So, we can just start writing down a proof and see where it takes us:

> Suppose that $x\in f^{-1}(U)$. We wish to demonstrate that there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $(x-\delta,x+\delta) \subseteq f^{-1}(U)$. Note that, by definition since $x\in f^{-1}(U)$, we have $f(x) \in U$. Since $U$ is open, there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(f(x)-\varepsilon,f(x)+\varepsilon)\subseteq U$.

Okay, so now we have a fairly clear goal: let's find a small enough $\delta$ such that the interval $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ maps, under $f$, to stay inside the interval $(f(x)-\varepsilon,f(x)+\varepsilon)$. To do that, the easiest thing to do is to consider how the function $x^2$ acts upon a small perturbation by considering $(x+e)^2 = x^2 + 2xe + e^2$. One can then note that if $e < \sqrt{\varepsilon / 2}$ and $|e| < \frac{\varepsilon}{4|x|}$, then we will necessarily have that $|(x+e)^2 - x^2| < \varepsilon$. In particular, this tells us how to complete the proof:

> We claim that if we set $\delta = \min(\sqrt{\varepsilon/2}, \frac{\varepsilon}{4|x|})$ the interval $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ is within $f^{-1}(U)$. To see this, note that if $|y^2-x^2| < \varepsilon$, then $y\in f^{-1}(U)$ as well. By some algebra, we can find that this condition holds whenever $y\in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$, therefore this interval is a subset of $f^{-1}(U)$. Since we have shown that every arbitrary $x$ in $f^{-1}(U)$ is contained within some open interval contained in $f^{-1}(U)$, we may conclude that $f^{-1}(U)$ is itself open, hence $f$ is continuous.

Comment: thank you appreciate that :)

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to show this for $U=(a,b)$ (as open intervals form a base).

And $f^{-1}[(a,b)]=\{x: x^2 \in (a,b)\}$ can be $\emptyset$ or (union of) open interval(s) again, depending on $a$ and $b$, e.g. for $(0,1)$ we get $(-1,1)$, for $(-2,2)$ we have $(-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$ for $(0,2)$ we get $(-\sqrt{2},0) \cup (0,\sqrt{2})$ etc. It's handling some cases but doable if careful.